# Code compliant options for adding electric service to attic?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, attic

I'd like to add electrical service to my unfinished attic for two attic fans, led lighting, and a few low voltage sensors (e.g. wifi router, hard wired zigbee motion sensors pointed at the living space below).

I'd like to put the fans and the low voltage stuff on separate circuits w/ arc fault outlets.

Is the best option just to run to separate circuits from outside main panel to feed these? Or is there an option to add a small panel from the main panel with its own circuit breakers for the two circuits?

Thank you!

My current setup:

- 200 AMP Main Service Panel

  - **Location:** Outside
  - **Services:** Solar, Unused Car Charger, and feeds sub panel. Has space for 4 breakers.
- 200 AMP Sub Panel

  - **Location:** Inside the house in an accessible location; not in attic
  - **Services**: lights, appliances, HVAC, outlets, etc. Very full. Has space for 2 breakers.

Note: all the circuit runs from the subpanel are in the attic as well.

Comment: It seems as if the loads you'll be adding are so minor that they could reasonably be powered by whatever existing circuits you can find on the attic floor -- surely there are ceiling lights whose junction boxes could accommodate one more cable being added. You could instead splice into any of those circuit home-runs with a new junction box (or two, if there's not enough slack in the cable).

Comment: A light circuit that uses LEDs for the ceiling below will probably have enough excess power to power everything you want, unless the attic fans uses a lot of power.

Comment: Re: "Or is there an option to add a small panel from the main panel with its own circuit breakers for the two circuits?" What's the advantage of this? Location  of panel? Running out of room for more breakers on main panel? Plans for later adding more circuits in/near attic?

Comment: Adding a panel would give me some more flexibility for the future.

Is adding a small dedicated panel, which is fed from the main panel, in the attic code compliant?